# CKEditor: Cannot Upload Image By Drag & Drop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor

It is weird because I have successfully uploaded the file. I returned the response like this:

```
"{\"uploaded\":1,\"fileName\":\"240_F_92535664_IvFsQeHjBzfE6sD4VHdO8u5OHUSc6yHF.jpg\",\"url\":\"https://localhost:44391/assets/images/newsletter/240_F_92535664_IvFsQeHjBzfE6sD4VHdO8u5OHUSc6yHF.jpg\"}"
```

There is notification shown in the editor "File successfully uploaded" then followed by another error message "Undefined".

[image]

The image is saved successfully, I can even browse the image from the browser `https://localhost:44391/assets/images/newsletter/240_F_92535664_IvFsQeHjBzfE6sD4VHdO8u5OHUSc6yHF.jpg`

What is happening here?

Comment: How are you showing your notifications in your View? Can you show your View code?

Comment: Please provide view code which contains how to show either green or red notification box (also use console.log to see where `undefined` value comes from).

Comment: Please look here it may help you: https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/829#issuecomment-453027294

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was because I was returning JSON string. I use json stringify for the response. After I changed it into pure object like:

```
Public obj getImage()
{
    return obj;
}
```

Before I was returning:

```
Public string getImage()
{
    return jsonString;
}
```

It runs OK.